# Why is Eve so sure about Father Kinley going to hell?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, lucifer

I was thinking about what Eve said to Father Kinley in Season 4, Episode 9, when he told him to get a demon from hell and try to convince Lucifer to come back. What does Eve mean saying that?

There was this conversation between Eve and Father Kinley,

> *Father Kinley:* Why would you think I'm going to hell?
>
> *Eve:* Just a hunch.

Why is that she's so sure he will go to hell? Although Father Kinley has set up murders before, but all was to a good cause, after all, to stop the prophecy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Lucifer, its explained that Hell is where a person goes to punish themselves. Lucifer and his dad have no bearing on people ending up there, it is up to the person. this is explained by Lucifer himself when Cain is dying. this is also why Lucifer punished himself about the death of his brother. pretending not to feel guilt doesn't stop Hell punishing you.

And While Father Kinley explains that what he did he did for the best of reasons, he definitely does feel guilty about it, and that was evident even to Eve while they were chatting. Eve knows the rules, maybe not in detail but enough to know that Father Kinley was indeed going to Hell

Comment: Hmm, I understood, but could be also a reason for Father Kinley to go on purpose in Hell in order to stop the prophecy?

Comment: It seems unlikely, Father Kinley was a priest, he truley believed in Heaven and Hell, he would definitely not want to go there by choice, but like a great many people he probably thought he could ask for forgiveness and then go to heaven, not knowing that his soul punishes itself